# Facebook share video does not generate description and link to page when posted

Tags: html, facebook, video

I was able to share the video on Facebook from our test site but the generated post varied from the size of the video's thumbnails. The portrait oriented image posted the video with a title, description, video, thumbnail  and a link to our page that users can click. The landscape oriented image on the other hand, did not contain any description from the og tags nor did it provide a link to our page where it was from.

What was required from us was title, description, video, thumbnail  and a link to our page. However, the wide thumbnails did not provide all those details in the generated post. 
The tall image is fine

[image]

The actual wide thumbnail result

[image]

Comment: have you checked [thispage](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)?

Comment: yes I did, that was how I was able to share an embedded video but there are missing details when sharing a video with a wide thumbnail. I am wondering if I can keep those details, description and link without forcing to re size the thumbnail to a thin picture

Comment: No, you can’t. Facebook decides how to display those posts. Users will still get to see the rest of the data, when they go to the single post view. But when they are displayed in newsfeed, you can not force it to display any certain way.